# simplest way to use javaScript to parse SVG path string to extract initial x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg

```
path[1].innerHTML
```

returns

```
  <path d="M 5,10 l0,0 l 15 ,0l0,15l-15,0l0,-15 z" ....
```

The first 2 digits after M are the x,y coordinates for the starting point of the SVG path.

```
path[1].innerHTML.substr(10,2)
```

returns the x cordinate (5) and

```
path[1].innerHTML.substr(13,2)
```

returns the correct y coordinate.
The problem is the values may be single or double or triple digit numbers which will break the substr() way of doing it.

Comment: So... don't rely on fixed indexes? You can use a regex or token-based parsing (e.g. split)

Comment: Or just use the built in methods and don't roll your own, likely buggy implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers have a [parser built in](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList), use it or you'll just spend your life on wheel reinventing and bugfixing.

Note for Chrome, you'll need to [use a polyfill](https://github.com/progers/pathseg)

```js
var path = document.getElementById("p");
var item1 = path.pathSegList[0];
alert("first co-ordinate is " + item1.x + ", " + item1.y);
```

```html
<svg>
    <path id="p" d="M 5,10 l0,0 l 15 ,0l0,15l-15,0l0,-15 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Note: 9/6/2018 9:08 PST this is throwing a console error.

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome, FF, and Edge. Chrome and FF threw the error. Edge (remarkably) did not.

Answer (score 3):

#### `getPathData()`

You can also use `getPathData()` method with a [polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) (currently still [a draft](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData) not natively supported).

```js
let path = document.querySelector('#path');
let pathData = path.getPathData();
let M = pathData[0]; //first M command
let [Mx, My] = M.values;
console.log('M coordinates:', Mx, My);
```

```html
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="5 10 15 15">
  <path id="path" d="M5 10l0 0l15 0l0 15l-15 0l0-15z" />
</svg>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@latest/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

#### Normalize path `d` attribute and split to array

The svg `d` attribute allows many shorthand notations like

- optional space between command letters and values: `M1 1`, `M 1 1`
- comma, space or minus (only for negative values) as delimiters `M -1,-1`, `M -1 -1`, `M-1-1`
- concatenated floating point values like `M.5.5`, `M 0.5 0.5`
- and others like repeated implicit commands `m.5.5 0 0`, `M 0.5 0.5 l0 0`

That's why we need to normalize/sanitize it before splitting.

However, if you only need the `M` starting coordinates of a path we can take a shortcut

```js
let d = path1.getAttribute('d');
let M = getMCoordinates(d);
console.log(M);



function getMCoordinates(d){
  
  let dArray = d
  // remove first M 
  .replace(/[Mm]/g, "")
  // remove new lines and tabs
  .replace(/[\n\r\t]/g, "")
  // replace comma with space
  .replace(/,|-/g, " ")
  // decompose multiple decimal delimiters like 0.5.5 => 0.5 0.5
  .replace(/(\.)(?=(\d+\.\d+)+)(\d+)/g, " $1$3 ")
  // split multiple zero valuues like 0 05 => 0 0 5
  .replace(/( )(0)(\d+)/g, "$1 $2 $3")
  .split(" ")
  .filter(Boolean);
    
  let M = {x: +dArray[0], y: +dArray[1]}
  return M;
  
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<!-- what a mess, but perfectly valid ... -->
  <path id="path1" d="
      
                      m.5.35.7 0 0 l 15    0l0,15l-15,0 l0,-15 z
"/>
</svg>
```

See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/ExroXdx) for a more complete regex parser.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to split your string based on its known format, and get your x,y where you expect them:

```
const path = "M 5,10 l0,0 l 15 ,0l0,15l-15,0l0,-15 z",
      splitted = path.split(" ")[1].split(","),
      x = splitted[0],
      y = splitted[1];
console.log(x,y);
```

You can also use regex, but it may not be simpler.

Comment: You won't catch `d="M5 10,10 1 ..."` with that, which is also valid data.

Comment: It gets "M5" as the first string.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but I can give you a failing example anyway: use other whitespace characters, or multiple like in "M 5,   \n\t10...". Point is: you must take intop account _all_ possibilities listed in the [grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF), and there are a few more than you can catch with simple splits.

Comment: That's right SVG path can get complicated. I answered the string thing, which is very simple. To handle svg correctly if it gets more complicated, I would advise against parsing the string anyway.

Comment: thanks very much - it works well for me... I am generating the paths myself anyway so i know the format before hand...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pathSegList` interface:

```
var path = document.querySelector('path');
var moveto =  path.pathSegList[0]; // always the first movoto command
var x = movoto.x, y = moveto.y
```