# SVG + Javascript: Find all numbers in path and create array, but keep other characters

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6, path, jquery-animate

My goal today is getting all Path elements from an inline SVG like so:

```
 <path d="M457,262c-75,284-118,142-228,142S-14,425,60,262c42-92,106,125,198-185 C368,7,484,163,457,262" />
```

```
 const path = blob.querySelector('path')!.getAttribute("d");
```

I would like to have an array like so:

```
['M','457',',','262','c-','75',',','284','-','118','.....']
```

Getting only numbers in an Array is of course possible with `path!.match(/\d+/g)`, but that doesn't give an complete array with all elements, numbers combined. Any ideas are really appreciated!

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Maybe use this: https://github.com/progers/pathseg

Comment: In short: Simple regex pattern might fail to parse highly minified `d` strings - there are too many ways to write a pathData `d` string. Better use a reliable parser like [getPathData() polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill). See  also [simplest way to use javaScript to parse SVG path string to extract initial x,y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271918/simplest-way-to-use-javascript-to-parse-svg-path-string-to-extract-initial-x-y-c).

Comment: It is weird to want to split up the path like that, because `c-` is not a thing. That minus belongs with the number that follows. It would be more useful to split it into its **meaningful** parts.

Answer (score 1):

The desired output is not in line with the meaning of the `d` attribute. For instance `c-` is not an atomic part of the syntax: the minus belongs with the digits that follow it -- to form a negative number.

The commas are just separators, so you would not really need them in the output.

Here is what you could do:

```js
let path = document.querySelector("path").getAttribute("d");

let parts = path.match(/[a-z]|[-+]?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)(e[-+]?\d+)?/gi)
                .map(x => isNaN(x) ? x : +x);
console.log(JSON.stringify(parts));
```

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
<path d="M457,262c-75,284-118,142-228,142S-14,425,60,262c42-92,106,125,198-185 C368,7,484,163,457,262" />
</svg>
```